# HTML and CSS help on nested div

Tags: html, css, xhtml

i'm doing a project for learning purpose. i have a problem of getting left and right div's inside the main div. if anyone can point me out where is the problem in the code it will be most appreciated. thank you

HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<link href="template/css/test_css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
<div id="main_wrapper">
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="head"></div>
  <div class="nav"></div>
  <div id="main">
  <div class="left">some data</div>
  <div class="right">some data</div>
  </div><!--end main--> 
  <div class="footer">
    </div><!--end footer-->  
    </div><!--end wrapper-->
</div><!--end main_wrapper-->
</body>
</html>
```

CSS code

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

body,td,th {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin-top:0px;
    background-color:#FF0000;
}

#main_wrapper {
width:950px;
margin:auto;
background-image: url(../images/bg_a.png);
background-repeat:repeat-y;
}


.wrapper {
background-color:#009900;
margin-left:5px;
margin-right:5px;
}
.head {
height:115px;
}

.nav {
height:30px;
}
#main {
padding:10px;
margin:5px;
background-color:#0099FF;
}
.left {
width:600px;
float:left;
}
.right {
width:300px;
float:right;
}
.footer {
height:50px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
   #main {
    padding:10px;
    margin:5px;
    background-color:#0099FF;
    overflow: hidden;
    }
```

Comment: Molecule's answer should be there. You've to add `overflow:hidden` to your `main` div.

Comment: Little trick to help you out next time... Add some 'background-color' to the CSS elements.